# shiny table not showing after deployment

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I am trying to render a data table on shinyapps but it is not showing. If I run it locally it shows up. I have 4 scripts and 1 data files, ui.R, server.R, helper1.R, helper2.R, DATA1.RDATA,

When I load DATA1.RDATA it becomes and object `data`.

I also source my two helper functions which will filter `data` and return a df. This line in server is suppose to call the functions in the helper scripts and return a df and render a data table.

```
output$overview_table <- renderDataTable(o_table(data,input$overview_year_level2),options = list(searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE, searchable = FALSE))
```

`ui.r`

```
library(shiny)
library(markdown)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Title",
                   tabPanel("Overview",
                            sidebarLayout(
                              sidebarPanel(uiOutput("overview_year_level")),
                              mainPanel(
                                imageOutput("overview_volume_value_pie"),
                                p(),
                                dataTableOutput("overview_table")
                              )
                            ))))
```

`server.R`

```
library(shiny)
source("helper1.R")
source("helper2.R")
load("DATA1.RDATA")




shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  ### OVERVIEW TABLE ###

  output$overview_year_level <- renderUI({
      selectInput("overview_year_level2","Select Year",c("Select",'2015','2016'),
                                                   "Select")
    }
  )

  output$overview_table <- renderDataTable({o_table(data,input$overview_year_level2)},
      options = list(searching = FALSE, paging = FALSE, searchable = FALSE))

})
```

`helper1.R`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(scales)
library(RColorBrewer)
require(gridExtra)
library(scales)

q_o_channel <- function (df,year1) {

  data <- df %>%
        filter(year == year1) %>%
        group_by(chnl) %>%
        summarize(volume = sum(volume)
                  ,value = sum(value))

  return(data)
}
```

`helper2.R`

```
o_table <- function(data,year1) {
  df <- q_o_channel(data,year1)
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: get rid of the curly brackets in the first argument of renderDataTable({})?

Comment: just tried that, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed**

I updated `R` and `shiny` and the problem was fixed.